# Access variable from a class in another class (by declaring the variable in "class Name: heritage {}")

Tags: swift, macos, class, cocoa

I want to access the `password` property of `Menu` in `ChangePasswordClass` to check if `oldPassword` is equal to `password`. How do I use `password` in the `ChangePasswordClass` class?  I can not use `Menu.password` because it gives me the error

> Instance member 'password' cannot be used on type 'Menu'

**Menu.swift:**

```
import Cocoa

class Menu: NSViewController {
    //Textfields
    @IBOutlet var passwordBoxShowed: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordBoxHidden: NSSecureTextField!
    //Menu Buttons
    @IBOutlet var connectButton: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet var changePasswordButton: NSButton!
    //Show password box
    @IBOutlet var showPasswordBox: NSButton!

    //Password show or not
    @IBAction func showPassword(_ sender: NSButton) {
        if showPasswordBox.state == 1 {
            passwordBoxHidden.isHidden = true
            passwordBoxShowed.isHidden = false
            passwordBoxShowed.stringValue = passwordBoxHidden.stringValue
        } else if showPasswordBox.state == 0 {
            passwordBoxHidden.isHidden = false
            passwordBoxShowed.isHidden = true
            passwordBoxHidden.stringValue = passwordBoxShowed.stringValue
        } else {

        }
    }
    //Password verification process
    var password = "1234"
    @IBAction func connexionTrigger(_ sender: NSButton) {
        if passwordBoxHidden.stringValue == password {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "passwordSegue", sender: self)
        } else {
            // password error
        }
    }
    //change password process
    @IBAction func changePasswordTrigger(_ sender: NSButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "changeSegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

**ChangePasswordClass.swift:**

```
import Cocoa

class ChangePasswordClass: NSViewController {
    // TextFields
    @IBOutlet var oldPassword: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet var newPassword: NSTextField!
    // Button
    @IBOutlet var changeButton: NSButton!
    //Changing Password process
    @IBAction func changePasswordTrigger(_ sender: NSButton) {
        if oldPassword.stringValue != nil && newPassword.stringValue != nil {
            if Menu.password == true {

            } else {

            }
        } else {

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

Comment: Not really sure what the problems is, please provide us your code samples.

Answer (score 0):

`password` is an instance property of the class `Menu`, but the syntax you are using to access it is for accessing a type property.

Depending on the exact use case, you have two options:

1. If the password will be the same regardless of the instance of your view controller class, declare `password` as a static variable and your code will work. `static var password = "1234"`
2. If the password should be different for each instance of the `Menu` class, you need to pass a reference of the `Menu` instance you are referring to the `ChangePasswordClass` instance before navigating to that class.

Moreover, change this piece of code:

```
if Menu.password == true {

} else {

}
```

`password` is a `String`, so it cannot be compared to a `Bool` and the comparison also wouldn't make any sense.